# node.js responds twice

Tags: node.js, debian

I've got a strange behavior with my fresh install of node ( from git ) on a debian machine.
It seems that the problem is not in my code, cause everything is working good on windows.
I already know that's it's not a favicon problem.

here is what I wrote :

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server) 
  , url = require('url')
  , qs = require('querystring')
  , request =  require('request')
  , fs = require('fs')
```

followed by

```
server.listen(3000); 
app.post('/postReload', function (req, res) {
  var fullBody = '';
  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    fullBody += chunk.toString();
    if (fullBody.length > 1e6) {
        req.connection.destroy();  
    }
  });
  req.on('end', function() {        
    out = qs.parse(fullBody);
    vars = out.vars || ''; 
    if(out.module && out.value){ 
        // do the job
        // console.log here is done twice !
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}) 
    res.end(); 
 });
});
```

When writing another way :

```
app.post('/postReload', function (req, res) {
  // console.log here is done twice !
}
```

The problem affects every browser, and one week of test did not solve nothing.

Someone here got an idea?

The double action happens on curl, or accessing by the browser.

Comment: Does it log twice immediately one after another or in two minutes?

Comment: twice immediatly for the same post. If a generate a random number on post server side, the same number is repeated twice

Comment: This is a long shot...but I suspect something in your code might be triggering the extra request 'end' event. You might want to strip down your code to the bare minimum (e.g. no body parsing, no length validation, et cetera) and just leave the console.log() to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

Merci Hector Correa.

This was the way i declared socket.io ...
my new and simple code is :

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
console.log('Only one time !!!')
res.end();
})
```

i go on noding now.